# 「かえって疎まれる」の意味について

Tags: meaning

「疎{うと}まれる」の意味はわかりますが、「かえって疎まれる」と使われたら意味がわからなくなりました。
「かえって」とは何を表すのですか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

この「かえって」は、「逆に」、「反対に」、「予想と違って」という意味を持ちます。

「却って」または「反って」と、漢字で書かれることもありますが、多くの場合はカナで書きます。

ですから、「かえって疎{うと}まれる」とは、「逆に嫌われる」、「予想に反して人から嫌がられる」という意味になります。

また、同じ発音の「帰って」とは意味・用法の異なる言葉ですのでご注意ください。