# What does the かえって mean

Tags: meaning

山中さんは手術したばかりだから、お見舞いに行ってはかえって迷惑だろう。

そんなに褒め言葉を言われては、かえって恥ずかしいです。

What does the かえって mean in the above statements?

Comment: Duplicate of https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/60803/%e3%81%8b%e3%81%88%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a6%e7%96%8e%e3%81%be%e3%82%8c%e3%82%8b-%e3%81%ae%e6%84%8f%e5%91%b3%e3%81%ab%e3%81%a4%e3%81%84%e3%81%a6

Comment: @l'électeur is there some kind of agreement for marking questions as duplicates when one question is written in English and another is in Japanese? I feel that many people who might have trouble with かえって might not know enough Japanese to understand the contents of your link. Content-wise of course, it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you consult an online dictionary, such as [Jisho](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%8B%E3%81%88%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6) or [Weblio](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%8B%E3%81%88%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6), you'll find that it means *instead* or *on the contrary*.

In your first example sentence, the speaker intended to visit Yamanaka to provide support or comfort, but reflects that doing so might be taxing for Yamanaka, who has just undergone surgery. There's a contrast between the speaker's intention to visiting Yamanaka and the likely outcome of the visit.

In your second example sentence, the speaker is being praised so excessively that they feel embarrassed, which again contrasts with the intent behind the praise.